# Как вывести данные в C# из mySQL из всех столбцов для одной строки

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть фрагмент кода. Нужно вывести все данные одной строки в `list<string>`

```
            Query.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = " + ID;
            MyDataReader = Query.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable schemaTable = MyDataReader.GetSchemaTable();

            foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
            {
                    var k = row[0];//временная тестовая переменная

            }
```

Сейчас `var k` принимает имена столбцов. А надо значения. Не могу найти инфу как это сделать. Нужно ли вообще для этого использовать `DataTable` или `MySqlDataReader` достаточно?

Примечание: понимаю и знаю, как вывести результаты запроса, если указывать имена столбцов в запросе, но их около 50, думаю это будет глупо.

Другой рабочий вариант (тут цикл выполняется один раз и возвращает только одно значение)

```
        Query.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID =" + ID;
        MyDataReader = Query.ExecuteReader();

        while (MyDataReader.Read())
        {
            listName.Add(MyDataReader.GetString(0));
        }
        MyDataReader.Close();`
```

Comment: может row[0].Value?

Comment: Что-то типо этого))) я думаю. Но Value не принимает в качестве метода)

Comment: тогда так row[0][0]

Comment: Вопрос `MyDataReader.GetSchemaTable();` поидее возвращает метаданные таблицы, соответственно вы и получаете имена столбцов. Почему бы не использовать `MyDataReader = Query.ExecuteReader();
        while (MyDataReader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", MyDataReader[0]));
        }`

Comment: Я пытался, но такой запрос выдает одно значение. Первого столбца. Чтобы получить тоже для второго - нужно указать его в CommandText. Поэтому и возник DateTable (видимо не к месту)

Comment: Atlantis, снова нет((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
public List<string> GetListFromRowById(int id, string connectionString, out string dbErrorMessage)
{
    DataTable table = null;
    List<string> row = null;
    dbErrorMessage = null;
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = @id";
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);
            }
            row = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    row.Add(table.Rows[i][j].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        dbErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    return row;
}
```

И использование функции:

```
string dbErrorMessage = null;
List<string> rowList = new List<string>();
rowList = GetListFromRowById(5, ConnectionString, out dbErrorMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для чтения данных предназначен `MyDataReder` его и нужно использовать.

```
Query.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Hookah_main WHERE ID_Hookah = " + Hookah_ID;
MyDataReader = Query.ExecuteReader();
DataTable schemaTable = MyDataReader.GetSchemaTable();

while (MyDataReader.Read())
{
    for (var i = 0; i < MyDataReader.FieldCount; i++)
    { 
        listName.Add(MyDataReader.GetString(i));
    }
}
MyDataReader.Close();
```

Comment: Что собственно я и сказал, только цикл перечисления столбцов не обязателен, можно по имени столбца обращаться. `MyDataReader["ColumnName"]`

Comment: У меня была трудность именно в этом. Нужно все столбцы, а их много